# how to add number of button in run time in android

Tags: android, mobile, android-layout

I am beginner in android development and my problem is that ı  want to add some buttons in runtime. I mean, number of button will be change according to flow of program so i need to create different number of buttons at different situations. In code section i can handle it by using array but what about layout file? how can ı set the layout file according to flow of program. I hope ı could explain my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The xml files in res/layout are static descriptions of layouts. **You can create different ones to be used in different contexts** (different activities, dialogs, etc). You can actually even replace one layout with another one in the same activity. **What you cannot do is to modify the xml files during runtime**.

If your UI depends on runtime variables, then you will have to act accordingly. If it's just the number of buttons that will change, you can either

1. Add new buttons using `addView(button);`
2. Add a ListView to your xml file and use an ArrayList and an ArrayAdapter to determine how many buttons you will need.